# ECS not an option in AWS CLI?

Tags: command-line, amazon-ec2

I'm just getting started with Amazon EC2 Container Service and I'm trying to follow this guide:

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_AWSCLI.html

I'm on puTTY (ubuntu) and I signed in and got the AWS CLI with a

```
sudo apt-get install -y awscli
```

(note: I am a Mac user, new to all of this) But now when I try to run the first command in the dev guide, I get an error:

```
$ aws ecs create-cluster --cluster-name MyCluster
usage: aws [options] <command> <subcommand> [parameters]
aws: error: argument command: Invalid choice, valid choices are:

autoscaling                              | cloudformation                                  
cloudfront                               | cloudsearch                                     
cloudtrail                               | cloudwatch                                      
datapipeline                             | directconnect                                   
dynamodb                                 | ec2                                             
elasticache                              | elasticbeanstalk                                
elastictranscoder                        | elb                                             
emr                                      | iam                                             
importexport                             | kinesis                                         
opsworks                                 | rds                                             
redshift                                 | route53                                         
ses                                      | sns                                             
sqs                                      | storagegateway                                  
sts                                      | support                                         
swf                                      | s3api                                           
s3                                       | configure                                       
help
```

Answer (score 1):

ECS is a relatively new service, perhaps the version that apt-get gives us doesn't have that option yet. After apt-get installing awscli on ubuntu, the version is 1.2.9, whereas the one I downloaded from the site onto my machine is 1.7.36.....

The aws ecs command works from my command prompt after I manually downloaded the AWS cli, so it's definitely there, just not in this version.